# For every $\lambda \in C$ with $|\lambda| = 1$, there exists a unitarian matrix $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I prove:

> *For every $\lambda \in C$, with $|\lambda| = 1$, there exist unitarian matrix $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.*

I tried to find a counterexample and I was not succeeded. I believe I need to prove that statement. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The adjective is "unitary" (unless you are referring to religion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it is well known any eigenvalue$~\lambda$ of a unitary matrix$~U$ has $|\lambda|=1$; this is so because of $v\in\Bbb C^n$ is a corresponding eigenvector then $0\neq v^*v=v^*U^*Uv=(\lambda v)^*(\lambda v)=\lambda\overline\lambda\,(v^*v)$, so $1=\lambda\overline\lambda=|\lambda|^2$.

To conversely show that for each $\lambda\in\Bbb C$ with $|\lambda|=1$ there exists a unitary matrix with eigenvalue$~\lambda$, it suffices to consider $1\times 1$ matrices; these are unitary if and only if their unique entry $a$ has $|a|=1$. If you insist on having a square matrix of a given size$~n$, then you can, provided that $n>0$, take a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries all have norm$~1$ (so that it is unitary) and at least one of them equals$~\lambda$; for instance take $\lambda I_n$. For $n=0$ you cannot find such a matrix, because the $0\times0$ matrix has no eigenvalues at all.

Comment: What if we expand to $2 \times 2$ or $n \times n$ how will your proof hold?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Do you want to prove for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and for all $\lambda\in\Bbb C$ that $|\lambda|=1$ is equivalent to "there exists a unitary $n\times n$ matrix with eigenvalue$~\lambda$"?

Comment: Yes, because I don't think that it suffices to consider just $1 \times1$ matrices. We need to consider all the possibilities that their $ \lambda$ is $|\lambda| = 1$. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda=a+ib$, with $\lvert \lambda\rvert^2=a^2+b^2=1$. The matrix
$$
U=\left(\begin{array}{rr} a & -b \\ b & a\end{array}\right)\in\mathbb R^{2\times2}
$$
is unitary, and its eigenvalues are $\lambda,\overline{\lambda}$.

Comment: With the assumption that $|\lambda|=1$?

Comment: @Jack Indeed, that was necessary!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda|=1$. Then $\lambda = e^{it}$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Now consider the matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & E_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}.$$
What are the eigenvalues of $A$? And is this unitary?

Comment: What does $|\lambda|$ mean? And how can we use $\lambda = e^{it}$ to prove?

Comment: You stated, that $|\lambda |=1$. You can use the identity, but don't have to.

Comment: I see. But I still dont understand the proof.

Comment: You should read your question again and you should try to understand what was your question. I think that then you will understand what you should do and that I already gave you the proof.